# Breaking out of a C++ recursive function within a for loop

Tags: c++, recursion

I am not able to break out of this C++ recursive function when the condition is met, I believe due to the fact that the for loop continues. Is there a way to break out of the entire thing at once (not just get out of the for loop, but finish the recursion at the same time)? Take set to be a char set of letters of the alphabet. It does reach the line where it outputs `cout << run << endl;` but it still doesn't terminate the program. Why is that?

```
bool printKString(char set[], string initial, 
                                    int n, int k, bool complete) 
{ 
    bool finished = false;
    if (k == 0) 
    { 
        if(initial.substr(0, 5) == "abcde") {
            cout << " - FOUND - " << initial << endl;
            complete = true;
        } 
        return complete;
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        string newPrefix;  
        newPrefix = prefix + set[i]; 
        bool run = printKString(set, newPrefix, n, k - 1, complete);
        if(run) {
            cout << run << endl;
            break;
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can actually return false when it's time to quit. You're not currently returning anything out of the bottom.

Comment: ... which means that your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements, or the solutions themselves into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Comment: returning false at the bottom of the function doesn't fix the problem that it doesn't break out of the for loop at the desired time.

Comment: Replace the break with a `return`

Comment: Try changing the `break` statement to `return run` (the return value to be adjusted based on your need).   A `break` will only break out of the enclosing scope (the `for` statement), not return to the (potentially recursive) caller.  There also needs to be a `return` statement after the loop (in case the loop finishes) - "falling off the end" of a function causes the caller to have undefined behaviour.